# Field is empty in database after self-written clean_field is called

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to secure that each email can only be used once, thus having the following clean method

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
.
.
.

    def clean_email(self):
        """
        Check if that email already exists in the database
        """
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError("This email already exists")    
        return email
```

and all the checks works as intended. The issue is that after the user is created, the email field is empty. Even if I hardcode the returned-email i.e

```py
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
   email = forms.EmailField()
.
.
.
   def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Der er allerede en bruger med den email")    
        return "my_email@email.com"
```

it is still empty in the database when the user is created.

I have attached the view aswell below, if that could be it

```py
#views.py

def register(request):
    if request.method=="POST": #post request
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Yey - success! Log in here ")
            return redirect("login")
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()

    return render(request,"users/register.html",context= {"form":form})
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: So in the second case, indentation is incorrect and clean_email() method isn't part of the form. Is that a real issue or copy mistake?

Comment: Its ist a copy mistake - it's running fine. The issue is just that the value is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserCreationForm from django.contrib.auth doesn't have a facility to save additional fields. It only handles the username (more precisely the field defined as USERNAME_FIELD on the model returned by `get_user_model()`) and the password.

You need to do the following in your view:

```py
        ...
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, "Yey - success! Log in here ")
            return redirect("login")
```

Comment: I have searched all the documentation through! I thought it was something like that, but haven't figured it out. THanks a bunch!